# Creating a separate column from the string values from another column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `df` that looks like this:

| Provider | fid | pid | datetime | score | system |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHE-229 | 2bfc9a62 | 2f43d557 | 2021-09-26 | -3.0 | SOFA |
| CHE-229 | 78d5d845 | 88c59d92 | 2021-09-12 | -4.0 | SAPS |

I would like to create a new column specific to the values from **system**.
e.g. I want to create a new column called **SOFA** and another column called **SAPS** with their respective scores in their table.

The output I want is:

| Provider | fid | pid | datetime | SOFA | SAPS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHE-229 | 2bfc9a62 | 2f43d557 | 2021-09-26 | -3.0 |  |
| CHE-229 | 78d5d845 | 88c59d92 | 2021-09-12 |  | -4.0 |

Answer (score 1):

You can get this with an iterative procedure using [`numpy.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to choose the value depending on a condition, and then dropping the original columns:

```
for sys in df["system"].unique():
    df[sys] = np.where(df["system"] == sys, df["score"], None)
df = df.drop(columns=["system", "score"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.pivot(df.columns[:-2], 'system', 'score').fillna('').reset_index()

system Provider       fid       pid    datetime SAPS SOFA
0       CHE-229  2bfc9a62  2f43d557  2021-09-26      -3.0
1       CHE-229  78d5d845  88c59d92  2021-09-12 -4.0
```

If you want them as numeric, then you can remove the `fillna()` part or even fill the nan with 0. ie `.fillna(0)`